# Haskell: getting more informative exceptions

Tags: haskell, exception

Suppose I have two functions:

```
not_force_eval :: IO (Either SomeException [[[Integer]]])
not_force_eval = (try $ evaluate [[[3 + 4, 6 * 2, 5 `div` 0]]])
                    :: IO (Either SomeException [[[Integer]]])

force_eval :: IO (Either SomeException [[[Integer]]])
force_eval = (try $ evaluate $!! [[[3 + 4, 6 * 2, 5 `div` 0]]]) 
                    :: IO (Either SomeException [[[Integer]]])
```

`force_eval` is almost the same as `not_force-eval` except for having `($!!)`, that's why the expression `` [[[3 + 4, 6 * 2, 5 `div` 0]]] `` is force evaluated.

Then I try to find out whether my fuctions throw any exceptions.

```
show_res = do
    res <- force_eval
    case res of
        Left exc   -> print $ displayException exc
        Right smth -> print smth
```

And running `show_res` I get:

> "divide by zero"

then I replace `force_eval` by `not_force_eval`

```
show_res = do
    res <- not_force_eval
    case res of
        Left exc   -> print $ displayException exc
        Right smth -> print smth
```

Running `show_res` I obviously get:

> [[[7,12,*** Exception: divide by zero

So, the question: is there any way to get the result that has been evaluated before the exception is thrown? For example, I'd like to make a string like:

> "divide by zero; [[[7,12, ..."

Comment: I don't think there's a general way which can do that without having to change the exception-throwing code. I think you have to rework it so that e.g. you call `show`, evaluate char-by-char the result, expecting some exception at every step. You could write `foo :: String -> IO (String, Maybe Exception)` so that the resulting string is the longest non-exceptional prefix, and any possible exception is reported.

Comment: @chi I had some similar thoughts. But can you, please, explain how to evaluate the result char-by-char?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could exploit something like: (untested)

```
safePrefix :: String -> IO (String, Maybe SomeException)
safePrefix s = do
   r1 <-try (evaluate s)
   case r1 of
      Left exc -> return ("", Just exc)
      Right "" -> return ("", Nothing)
      Right (x:xs) -> do
         r2 <- try (evaluate x)
         case r2 of
            Left exc -> return ("", Just exc)
            Right x' -> do
               (p, exc) <- safePrefix xs
               return (x':p, exc)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I need. For somebody who wants to use it: to make the code work replace, ```Exception``` by, for example, ```SomeException```.